# TFS Not Loading Custom Assemblies

Tags: tfs, process, build, assemblies

I am having problems trying to get my Build Controller/Agents to pick up on a custom assembly from the reference used in my Build Process Template.

I have read about this problem extensively across several blogs and unfortunately I have been unable to resolve this issue:

[image: TFS Build Error Log]]

I can confirm the following:

1. TFS 2012 with no updates Visual Studio 2013, Update 1 (to create the
   activity and upgrade the build process template)
2. One Build Controller with mutiple agents
3. The TFS Assembly checked in and within source control

[image: Custom Assembly Checked In]]

The correct path is set within the build controller with the service restarted:
[image: [Build Controller Settings]

The custom activity is resolving correctly within the template when following the guide lines used in these blogs:

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx

[image: Build Process Template - Custom Activity Resolving Correctly (assembly updater)]

I can view the the reference within the XAML of the Build Process Template and it looks fine with no validation errors and my code activity appears to be implemented correctly.

**Code below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace FireWatch.TFS
{
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class AssemblyUpdater : CodeActivity
    {
        #region Static Methods
        #endregion   

        #region Property Variables
        #endregion

        #region Constants and Read-Onlys
        private const string ASSEMBLY_VERSION_REG_EX = @"\(""\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+""\)";
        private const string ATTRIBUTE_REG_EX = "AssemblyVersion";
        #endregion

        #region Accessors

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<int> Major { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<int> Minor { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<int> Build { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<Workspace> Workspace { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Encapsulation

        private void UpdateAssemblyInfo(IEnumerable<string> assemblyInfos, int major, int minor, int build)
        {
            foreach (string myAssemblyInfo in assemblyInfos)
            {
                string myFileText = File.Exists(myAssemblyInfo) ? File.ReadAllText(myAssemblyInfo) : string.Empty;

                if (myFileText != string.Empty)
                {
                    Regex myRegex = new Regex(ATTRIBUTE_REG_EX + ASSEMBLY_VERSION_REG_EX);
                    Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(myFileText);

                    if (myMatch.Success)
                    {
                        string myVersionNumber = myMatch.Value.Substring(ATTRIBUTE_REG_EX.Length + 2,
                                                 myMatch.Value.Length - ATTRIBUTE_REG_EX.Length - 4);

                        Version myCurrentVersion = new Version(myVersionNumber);
                        Version myNewVersion = new Version(major, minor, build, (myCurrentVersion.Revision + 1));

                        string myUpdatedAssemblyText = myRegex.Replace(myFileText, ATTRIBUTE_REG_EX + "(\"" + myNewVersion + "\")");

                        File.WriteAllText(myAssemblyInfo, myUpdatedAssemblyText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void CheckOut(Workspace workspace, IList<string> assemblyInfos)
        {
            if (workspace != null && assemblyInfos != null && assemblyInfos.Any())
            {
                workspace.PendEdit(assemblyInfos.ToArray());
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetRelevantAssemblyInfos(Workspace workspace)
        {
            IList<string> myReturn = new List<string>();

            PendingChange[] myPendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();

            foreach (PendingChange myPendingChange in myPendingChanges)
            {
                string myPath = AssemblyInfoPresent(myPendingChange);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myPath))
                {
                    myReturn.Add(myPath);
                }
            }

            return myReturn;
        }

        private string AssemblyInfoPresent(PendingChange pendingChange)
        {
            string myReturn = string.Empty;

            if (pendingChange != null)
            {
                string myParentDirectory = pendingChange.LocalItem;
                string myParentLevelAssemblyInfo = myParentDirectory + @"\AssemblyInfo.cs";

                string myPropertiesDirectory = pendingChange.LocalItem + @"\Properties";
                string myPropertiesLevelAssemblyInfo = myParentDirectory + @"\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs";

                if (Directory.Exists(myPropertiesDirectory) && File.Exists(myPropertiesLevelAssemblyInfo))
                {
                    myReturn = myPropertiesLevelAssemblyInfo;
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(myParentDirectory) && File.Exists(myParentLevelAssemblyInfo))
                {
                    myReturn = myParentLevelAssemblyInfo;
                }
            }

            return myReturn;
        }

        #endregion

        #region CodeActivity Members

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            int myMajor = context.GetValue(this.Major);
            int myMinor = context.GetValue(this.Minor);
            int myBuild = context.GetValue(this.Build);
            Workspace myWorkspace = context.GetValue(this.Workspace);

            IList<string> myAssemblyInfos = GetRelevantAssemblyInfos(myWorkspace).Distinct().ToList();

            if (myAssemblyInfos.Any())
            {
                CheckOut(myWorkspace, myAssemblyInfos);
                UpdateAssemblyInfo(myAssemblyInfos, myMajor, myMinor, myBuild);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you restarted the machine? try clearing the cache on the build machine at

C:\Users\ **BUILDACCOUNT**\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController\2.0\Assemblies

C:\Users\ **BUILDACCOUNT**\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\ **BUILDAGENTNO**\Assemblies

either way should force the build controller to download the latest assemblies

Comment: Our build controller gets restarted on a nightly basis but the build agent has not been restarted. I will look to restart my build agent tonight and hopefully that may resolve the issue. I appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this has not resolved the issue. I appreciate the help, have you any solid tutorials that show how to extend a code activity that I can try? Simply because there is the possibility that I have missed a step. I am fairly confident I haven't though.

Comment: Hi, yeah I can confirm they both exist on the build controller and the build agent. So I would assume it may be a reference issue within my build template xaml?

Comment: Yes i would assume so, there seems to be an 'activities' in you dll name but not in your namespace, sorry hard to debug remotely, cant spot anything else that stands out

Comment: Ok much appreciated, I will try and have a look to resolve the issue. Thanks for your help. I will also come back with the actual issue if I find it.

Comment: no problem be interesting to hear, one final stab, Is the dll under source, the latest version, i.e. the same version you are using on your development box to alter the template

Comment: Unfortunately I have made a rookie mistake of not updating the AssemblyInfo of my FireWatch.Activities.dll so I cannot tell if it is the same version or not. I will make changes and test it to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this problem was resolved by using TFS 2013 with the latest service pack. The custom assemblies are now loaded without issue.